# How to configure a Spring 3 consumer for activemq 5 over SSL

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am trying to create an SSL connection to activemq (using Spring 3.1, ActiveMQ 5.5, and Camel 10.0).  I'm getting the dreaded SSL handshake exception.  I can connect with an openssl s_client using the certificate in the jks.  Thus, I'm trying to figure out if there is a problem with my keystore (which seems to work in other situations - e.g. with tomcat) or a problem with my XML configuration.  Does anyone have a good example, thoughts about other ways to test, or see what I'm doing wrong?

Please note, my config passes validation (in case you see a typo).

Thanks
-J

```
<bean id="myJmsRedeliverPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliverPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="500"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsSecureConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="ssl://test.com:8100"/>
    <property name="redeliverPolicy" ref="myJmsRedeliverPolicy"/>
    <property name="keyStore" value="/usr/lib/mykeystore.jks"/>
    <property name="keyStorePassword" value="mypass"/>
    <property name="trustStore" value="/usr/lib/mycacerts"/>
    <property name="trustStorePassword" value="changeit"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="pooledSecureConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsSecureConnectionFactory"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="txSecureManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledSecureConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="jmsSecureConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledSecureConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txSecureManager"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="activemqs" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsSecureConfig" />
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your application with:
`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

to get further with your troubleshooting. Usually, that command provides printout that says pretty much exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was using that to debug.  I got it (sort of) working by setting the keystore and truststore information in the JVM rather than setting it in the ConnectionFactory (as above).  Any thoughts as to why one would work and the other would not?

Comment: Ok. I usually do it with JVM parameters, but anyway. /usr/lib/mykeystore.jks seems not to be in your classpath, right?

 `<property name="keyStore" value="file:///usr/lib/mykeystore.jks"/>` would probably be the correct syntax for this, since you want to grab a file system keystore.

I would suggest reading this page: http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/security/FMQSecuritySSLClients.html for some info on the subject.